# Can we customize the users list view in the admin?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to customize the view of the users list page, i want to display only the rows with the meta value equals to `Mycenter`. I can do it using jQuery but it will no be secure.

Is there any filter to help me do it using php instead?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the `manage_users_custom_column`  filter:

exp:

```
add_filter('manage_users_custom_column',
function($value, $column_name, $user_id) {
    if ( 'center' == $column_name ) {
        if ('Mycenter' == $value) {
           return $value;
        } else {
           return "";
        }
     }
}
, 20, 3);
```

more info  [manage_users_custom_column](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_users_custom_column/)

Comment: I think it is for the posts not the users.

Comment: Can you provide an example for using it?

Comment: I don't have any errors and the column name is center.

Comment: debug using `if ( 'center' == $column_name ) {var_dump($value == 'Mycenter' );`

Comment: It returned false 3 times

Comment: then that means you don't have rows where the value is Mycenter

Comment: The $value is equal to 0 for the 3 rows

Comment: change the priority  to a higher number , i see that this column is a custom column so you need a higher priority , the 4th param of the add_filter is the priority

Comment: It hides only the values of the two columns "Phone Number" and "Car Number" not the whole row.

Comment: you want the whole row?

Comment: if you want the whole row removed then you need a custom query for the user list

Comment: you will need to remove the whole page and build another one with the custom query

Comment: 'add_filter('manage_users_columns','remove_users_columns');
function remove_users_columns($column_headers) {
    if (current_user_can('moderator')) {
      unset($column_headers['email']);
    }
 
    return $column_headers;
}'

Comment: I found this filter to remove columns, are there anything like this for rows?

Comment: No man you need a custom wp query on the users, and a custom page to display them